# What meat substitutes can be used in donairs?

Tags: lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, recipe-request, meat-substitutes

Donairs were a favourite of mine before I went vegetarian, and I haven't been able to figure out what I could use as a meat substitute in it. There are a lot of options, but I just don't have the money to try too many.

I want it to have a similar texture to donair meat. That's what's most important. Similar taste (once you put the sweet sauce on) would be nice as well, but texture really is important to me. Similarly, is the typical sweet sauce recipe vegetarian?

I live in Western Canada.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I think that when asking for products, it is generally helpful to mention your country/wider geographical area so that you can be given specific answers depending on what products are available there.

Comment: For clarity, are you looking for a meat substitute that is totally plant-based? Or are you okay with the substitute containing eggs and/or dairy?

Comment: i'm okay with it containing eggs and/or dairy

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've updated the tags on your question to help people answer in the context of your preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Seitan would be a great substitute, [one of the recipes I use can be found here.](http://www.thatwasvegan.com/2012/01/30/my-favorite-chicken-style-seitan-recipe/) You can spice the seitan appropriately for the recipe by adjusting the spices in the seitan recipe. You could either slice the loaves to the appropriate shape right away, or grind it (using a standard meat grinder or similar) and then press the ground seitan, possibly with some kind of binding agent, such as aquafaba or flaxseed egg, to get to the pressed loaf of ground meat texture that is the trademark of donairs, as you please.

Comment: Sounds good, but beware if you have celiac disease or a wheat intollerance.